# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter is thrown during migration from Spring 4 to Spring 6

Tags: spring, maven, spring-mvc, jakarta-migration

```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
```

I have Added Jakarta servlet dependencies . I have also added CORS filter in my web.xml

The following is the web.xml declaration of CORS filter

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.exposed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Access-Control-Allow-Credentials</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.methods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET,POST,HEAD,OPTIONS,PUT</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowed.headers</param-name>
        <param-value>Content-Type,X-Requested-With,accept,Origin,Access-Control-Request-Method,Access-Control-Request-Headers</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Please don't code as images, as that is unreadable and requires offsite clicks to get the full picture of your code. Spring 6 requires jakartaee, you cannot just upgrade Spring. Your question indicates Spring Boot as well, which is what you should upgrade not individual dependencies. You also need to make sure the dependencies you use are compatible and migrate your own code.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: Noted ,Removed the image attachment and added the web.xml snippet . Thanks for the headsup

Comment: @M.Deinum, I want to continue using spring MVC for now , I just wanted to upgrade java   and spring version for LTS, Is there any other work around rather than move to boot to overcome this issue

Comment: I'm not saying you should move to boot (it will make things easier). You will need to JakartaEE instead of JavaEE. \

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using `com.thetransactioncompany:cors-filter` with version lower than `3.0`, the `com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter` is implementing `javax.servlet.Filter` which is not compatible with your upgrade going to Spring6 which requires `jakarta-based` components.

You should upgrade the dependency to 3.0 to fix the issue; example of pom.xml extract below :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.thetransactioncompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>cors-filter</artifactId>
    <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue by a number of steps. All related to version compliance of dependencies to spring in my project:

1. base64 Encoder library with base64.
2. com.sun.ssl Library is depreciated in Spring 6.
3. javafx.scene.image is depreciated in Spring 6.
4. queryForInt is replaced with queryForObject(Integer.class).
5. Simplejdbctemplate is replaced with jdbctemplate library.
6. All javax libraries are replaced with jakarta EE.
7. Updated CORS filter  from web.xml as suggested by Laurent Schoelens.
8. Removed XML and SMS libraries used in library since I'm not going to use them now (will update here once I find replacement).